# ProgressDialog obsoleto en Android, ¿cómo cambiarlo por una ProgressBar en la barra de tareas?

Tags: android, progressbar

Actualizando mi App me encuentro con que [android](/questions/tagged/android) ha declarado el elemento [`ProgressDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)obsoleto:

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
>   dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
>   of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
>   ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
>   you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress.

Yo usaba `ProgressDialog` durante una petición `Volley` y ahora lo he cambiado por una `ProgressBar` sencilla, sin porcentajes ni nada...

Lo que pasa es que el elemento se muestra a la izquierda de mi `TextView`, y yo quisiera ponerlo en la `ToolBar`, a la derecha, pero no sé cómo puedo hacerlo.

**Código de la Activity que muestra el `ProgressDialog`:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, OL_URL + strFechaHoy,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        /*Obtenida la respuesta quitamos el pb*/
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        String resp = showOficio(response);
                        strContenido = Utils.fromHtml(resp);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        /*Obtenido un error, también quitamos el pb*/
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        VolleyErrorHelper errorVolley = new VolleyErrorHelper();
                        String sError = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);
                        mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(sError));
                    }
                }
        );

        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        /*Activamos la pb mientras se hace la petición*/
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

**Layout principal de la Activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.OficioActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_oficio" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Layout `content_oficio` donde se encuentra la `ProgressBar`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.OficioActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_oficio">
    <include layout="@layout/tv_zoomable" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

El toolbar permite agregar hijos porque sirve como contenedor (`ViewGroup`). Si no estas utilizando la `Toolbar` como contenedor, digase agregar menu_items o títulos, puedes intentar agregar un `FrameLayout` con tu `ProgressBar`. Por ejemplo:

. . .

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <FrameLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <ProgressBar
                 android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                 android:indeterminate="true"
                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="end"/>
       </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

. . .

Ahora bien, si estas en un `Fragment`, diferente al `Activity` que carga el Layout que contiene el `toolbar`. Para obtener la referencia del `ProgressBar` debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
if (activity.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
}
```

En este punto tienes un `ViewGroup` por lo que puedes buscar la referencia del `ProgressBar` y guardarlo en una variable para jugar con la visibilidad. Ejemplo:

```
toolbar.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

Según entiendo, tienes un `Activity` ya definido el cual es diferente al que carga el `Toolbar`. En este caso, si quieres utilizar el mismo `Toolbar` por toda la aplicacion, debes crear un Layout que contenga tu `Toolbar` e incluirlos en todos los Layouts que quieras utilizarlo, por ejemplo:

**toolbar_layout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Y lo incluyes en el `Layout` de tu Actividad donde quieras utilizar el mismo `Toolbar`:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout />
```

asi ya solo tendrías que buscar la referencias de tus hijos y customizar el toolbar a tu manera.

Nota: si tu app o activity ya tiene definido un estilo que utiliza un `Toolbar`, para poder reemplazarlo por el `Toolbar`, debes cambiar el estilo a `NoActionBar`. Ejemplo:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Para obtener la referencia de un `Layout` que ha sido incluido, basta con obtener el root del mismo. Puedes obtener mas informacion [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787008/how-to-access-button-inside-include-layout?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).