# ¿Como modificar el ActionBar de Navigation Drawer Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawerlayout, navigationview

Podemos decir que tengo lo mismo que te añade el propio Android Studio por defecto, sus layouts, sus activityes etc... Pero me gustaría modificar el ActionBar que me añade por defecto, y no encuentro en ningun lado donde está la configurqación del actionbar.
[image: Quiero modificar lo de la izquierda, los tres puntos de la derecha se que es un menú y demás pero la parta de la izquierda parece más bien un theme predeterminado que no me deja modificar.]

Por favor alguien podría ayudarme a modificar esta sección o al menos ayudarme a ubicarla en los XML's o en los Java's?

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve esta informacion, asi puedes ubicar y sustituir tu Toolbar por uno custom: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/161350/38154

Comment: ¿Intentas cambiar los íconos del action bar, es decir, el de "hamburguesa", o modificar todo el desplegable navigation drawer?

Comment: @AngelManuelElias efectivamente esa "Hamburguesa" que dices tu es lo que quiero modificar.

Comment: lo quieres cambiar por otro ícono u ocultarlo? el drawer icon esta en styles (drawerArrowStyle)

Comment: @armen Quiero cambiarlo por otro icono, no lo encuntro el drawerArrowStyle por ninguna parte. He estado mirando en todos lados: por los layouts, por los drawable, en style, en mainfest.... y no lo encuentro en ningún lado el icono para modificarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas editar el texto del ActionBar hazlo de la siguiente forma:

> manifests->AndroidManifest.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Texto que se mostrará en el actionBar" />
```

- Para editar el contenido del navegador:

> res->layout->nav_header_main.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Para agregar o editar los menus del navegador:

> res->menu->activity_main_drawer.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes crear grupos y dentro de este, items que serán los menus que se mostrarán.

Por ejemplo:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="@string/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_register"
        android:title="@string/register_nav" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_foods"
        android:title="@string/food" />
</group>
```

Para modificar el contenido de la activity:

> res->layout->content_main.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mas información: [Creación de un panel lateral de navegación](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer)

Comment: Me refiero a la "Hamburguesa" de al lado del texto Home

Comment: @DazzelWazzel solo quieres modificar la imagen de "hamburguer"?

Comment: @Jorgesys efectivamente.

Comment: @DazzelWazzel puedes probar con: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);` en el código del MainActivity

Comment: @chdzma no, esa constante "logo" no es la "hamburguesa" que quiero modificar, es como otro item a parte dentro de la toolbar, pero empiezo a pensar que no voy a poder quitarlo puesto que quito el setSupportActionBar() y demás configuraciones del toolbar y solo he conseguido hacer desaparecer el titulo "home" y el panel de menu de opciones de la esquina superior derecha. Pero gracias por el aporte :)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno finalimente he podido resolverlo, en este enlace lo resuelven en versiones anteriores y algunas no funcionan pero la que propone crear un Drawable personalizado desde el codigo y luego meterselo al propio ActionBarToggle dedse el codigo es la mejor solución.

```
//////HAMBURUGESA//////
    //Nos creamos nuestro Icono drawable personalizado
    Drawable burger = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.mipmap.cart_icon_pink_round, this.getTheme()); //Le pasamos el mipmap pero estamos creando drwaable no nos da problemas de momento
    //Instanciamos el Layout del Drawer
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //Instanciamos y construimos el ActionBarDrawerToggle
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);// Hay que decirle que deshabilite el burger actual
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(burger); //Le indico cual va a ser el Drawable que utilizará para sacar y meter el navigator
    //Creamos un listener especial él.
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });


    toggle.syncState();
    ////FIN HAMBURGUESA ////
```

[image: Aquí está el resultado final]

También os dejo aquí el link de referencia de donde finalmente aclaré todas mis dudas, por si alguien tiene curiosidad o tiene el mismo problema en un futuro.
Un saludo y gracias a todos los que han participado.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482825/changing-navigation-drawer-icon-on-action-bar-android